# Laravel default authentication iis8.5 not working

Tags: laravel, iis, iis-8.5

I have installed laravel 5.5 on a IIS 8.5 server 
I used laravels dafault authentication scaffolding  to create a register and login page .

I tested it on another machine running php and apache it works great.

But when i try and test the same login on my IIS 8.5 server  authentication seems to be not working .

My session driver is file 
I have given IUSR permissions full to storage vendors bootstrap .

I am able to retrieve data from the database and show on the page.

What i am not able to do is login , If i fill in the user name and password and click login it doesn't login and doesn't throw any error.

I am not trying to use ldap or windows authentication , I'm just using  the default login scaffolding  where user name and password is stored in my database .

Any one else experience this issue on IIS 8.5  ?

when i check the login method ,the below is the output when i do inside the login method

```
 protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
        {
        echo json_encode($request);die;

        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
```

Below is out put i dont see any values

```
{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}
```

Comment: did you try changing your env

Comment: Yes env  up to date .  I think it probably got to do with URL rewrite mod 2.0  may be it needs that .

Comment: Yes you need to install url rewrite,ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters,PHP. Import the Laravel .htaccess into URL Rewrite. make sure that your laravel project has  IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permission.